# Register page aligning to the top left corner of the main stage window of my JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

When I switch from login page to register page inside my JavaFX application main stage window, the register page align automatically to the top left corner. This only happens when I switch to the register page and back to the login page but works fine when switching to any other page of my application. I have already tried setting alignment for both the vbox and borderpane to center but it didn't work.

RegisterController.java -

```
public class RegisterController{
@FXML
private TextField email;

@FXML
private PasswordField password;

@FXML
private TextField name;

@FXML
private PasswordField confirmPassword;

@FXML
private DatePicker dob;

@FXML
private Hyperlink loginLink;

@FXML
private VBox container;


@FXML
public void handleLink(){
    PageLoader pageLoader = new PageLoader();
    pageLoader.loadPage("LOGIN",borderPane);
}

@FXML
public void handleRegister(){
}
}
```

Register.fxml -

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" style="-fx-background-color: 
#22705a;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="Gui.RegisterController">
<center>
<VBox fx:id="container" alignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <children>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="@../Media/logo.png" />
            </image>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="50.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</VBox>
</center>
</BorderPane>
```

LoginController.java -

```
public class LoginController {

@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;

@FXML
private TextField email;

@FXML
private PasswordField password;

@FXML
private Hyperlink registerLink;

@FXML
public void handleLogin(){
    Alert incorrectPassword = new Alert((Alert.AlertType.ERROR));
    incorrectPassword.setTitle("Fly High Travel Planner");
    incorrectPassword.setContentText("Your password is incorrect!");
    incorrectPassword.setHeaderText(null);

    Alert incorrectEmail = new Alert((Alert.AlertType.ERROR));
    incorrectEmail.setTitle("Fly High Travel Planner");
    incorrectEmail.setContentText("Your email id is incorrect!");
    incorrectEmail.setHeaderText(null);

    Alert emptyAlert = new Alert((Alert.AlertType.ERROR));
    emptyAlert.setTitle("Fly High Travel Planner");
    emptyAlert.setContentText("Both email and password are required!");
    emptyAlert.setHeaderText(null);

    try{
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Tour.db");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM user";
        statement.execute(query);
        ResultSet results = statement.getResultSet();
        boolean correctEmail = false;

        if (email.getText().trim().equals("") || password.getText().trim().equals("")){
            emptyAlert.showAndWait();
        } else {
            while (results.next()) {
                if (results.getString("email").equals(email.getText())) {
                    correctEmail = true;
                    if (results.getString("password").equals(password.getText())){
                        PageLoader pageLoader = new PageLoader();
                        pageLoader.loadPage("HOME",borderPane);
                        break;
                    }
                    incorrectPassword.showAndWait();
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!correctEmail)
                incorrectEmail.showAndWait();
        }

        statement.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleLink(){
    PageLoader pageLoader = new PageLoader();
    pageLoader.loadPage("REGISTER",borderPane);
    }

}
```

Login.fxml -

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" style="-fx-background-color: 
#22705a;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="Gui.LoginController">
<center>
   <VBox alignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
           <image>
              <Image url="@../Media/logo.png" />
           </image>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="50.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </ImageView>
     </children>
   </VBox>
</center>
</BorderPane>
```

PageLoader.java -

```
package Gui;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PageLoader {

private String pageFile;

public void loadPage(String button, BorderPane borderPane) {
    try {

        switch (button) {
            case "CONTACT":
                pageFile = "Contact.fxml";
                break;
            case "HOME":
                pageFile = "Home.fxml";
                break;
            case "ABOUT":
                pageFile = "About.fxml";
                break;
            case "LOGIN":
                pageFile = "Login.fxml";
                break;
            case "REGISTER":
                pageFile = "Register.fxml";
                break;
            default:
                pageFile = "Tours.fxml";
                break;
        }

        borderPane.getChildren().removeAll();
        BorderPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(pageFile));
        borderPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,e);
    }
}
}
```

Output -

[Login Page when application is started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwDtr.png)

[Registration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhd7a.png)

[Login Page when cominig back from registration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64W9g.png)

Comment: Did you try `borderpane.setAlignment(pane, Pos.CENTER);` after adding it in `PageLoader.java`?

Comment: [mcve] please (vs tons of unrelated code)

Comment: @Jagar yes, but that didn't work.

Comment: @kleopatra I have reduced the code to as minimum as possible for understanding the problem. Can you please check and help me now ?

Comment: There is a better practice then, you don't have to remove and add childs, but `1.` you can have 2 fxml so hide and show the another one or `2.` you can have them all in one 1 fxml file but change their visibility

Comment: @Jagar But hiding the fxml or the components in the fxml creates a gap in that place, doesn't it ? I don't want that gap.

Comment: You can hide that place too with using `setManaged(false);`

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly .. if you have a layout problem, there's no reason to show db code nor any alerts or other logic except switching the ui. At the same time, the example must be reproducible - Application, controllers, fxml, no references to stuff that's only available in your local context.

Comment: @Jagar Thanks. I changed the code to using setVisible() and setManaged() methods as you had suggested instead of deleting child nodes from the pane. It now works perfectly.